# Filter a database groupby output without storing it in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a data with Person ID in col1, which can repeat implying another row for same person.
col2 says whether that row (instance) is Y or N for some parameter.

Sample:

```
col1    col2
1       Y
1       Y
1       N
1       Y
1       N
2       Y
2       N
2       N
3       N
3       N
3       N
3       N
```

There are a million such rows.

I need to get a filtered output of those persons who only has 'N's and their count of 'N'.

So I did something like this:

```
data.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts().unstack(level=1)
```

This gets me the following:

```
col1    Y    N
1       3    2
2       1    2
3       NaN  4
```

But I only need the third row in that.

I tried applying a filter using following but they do not work.

```
data.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts().unstack(level=1)['Y'.isna()]
data.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts().unstack(level=1).query("'Y'.isna()")
```

I understand that I cannot refer to 'Y' column directly without adding the data variable before it in the format `data['Y']`. But I do not wish to save this groupby result in a new variable.

Any way we can filter the output without saving it to a variable?

For example:

```
data.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts().unstack(level=1)['Y'].isna().sum()
```

This will give me number of cases. However, I need col1 values too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `Y`:

```
>>> data.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts().unstack(level=1).query("Y.isna()")
col2    N   Y
col1         
3     4.0 NaN
>>>
```

Or with `True`:

```
>>> x = data.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts().unstack(level=1)
>>> x[x[True].isna()]
col2  False  True 
col1              
3       4.0    NaN
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this work if the case was boolean values True and False instead of Y and N? `.query("False.isna()")`

Comment: As of now, I could work around by adding a `.rename(columns={False:'N',True:'Y'})` after the unstack method to get this to work. Please suggest if there any another way.

Comment: Same goes for where col2 has integers 0 and 1 instead of Y and N strings.

Comment: @Meet Edited my answer

Comment: So, there's no way to do it without storing it to variable x, is there?

Comment: @Meet Yes unfortunately.

Comment: No issues. I used that `.rename` method to convert boolean to values and then use your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Meet Yes! An option, feel free to accept if you like, and upvote